# AEM - import static pages?

Tags: aem

We're considering using Adobe Experience Manager for an upcoming project.  But we have a number of pre-made static pages we'd like to import into this project.  What would be the best way to 'import' these pages into an AEM project?

Note: these pages are HTML that may contain some CSS and JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serve static HTML, CSS and JS files from AEM. There are multiple ways of getting your files in AEM including but not limited to:

1) Through CRXDE, goto `Create > Create File...` name your HTML file and save. On the `jcr:content` subnode, double click on the `jcr:data` binary property, upload your HTML file and click save.

2) cURL your files into AEM. See the documentation on the [SlingPostServlet](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#file-uploads). You can write a script in Bash, Python or your language of choice to loop over your files and POST to the AEM instance.

3) Go to CRXDE Package Manager, create a simple package, download it and unzip the file. Examine the contents of the zip including the `.content.xml` files and the `/META-INF/vault/filter.xml` file. Add your HTML files and update the package filters, zip up the files, upload the package to AEM through the CRXDE Package Manager and install.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what "nateyolles" has already mentioned,

Adobe Experience Manager provides several options (direct/Indirect) for either importing or exporting data (within the AEM tool they are labeled importers and are found under the tools area). Lets look at each option so you can decide which one will best service your current needs.

1. **Site Importer** – Allows you to import either a web page or an entire website into AEM. For site imports, you will need to need to specify the project title, site URL (of page or site to import), thumbnail image for the template, the sitemap (for the pages in CQ using the template) and whether or not you want to overwrite (if page or site exist in AEM)

**"Use of Site Importer tool"**

Link:- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/dev-tools/site-importer.html

***Note: Site Imported has been removed since AEM 6.3***

2. **Feed Importer** – The feed import option within Adobe Experience Manager provides the ability to import content via a feed (whether that be an RSS feed or an Atom feed). This can be extremely beneficial to blog creators, like myself, who might want to bring in the content of their blog (from say WordPress, Drupal or another CMS) into an AEM environment.
3. **Offline Importer** – This functionality, within Adobe Experience Manager, provides the ability to import content from Microsoft Office Word document files into AEM templates (ending with the file extension of .doc). Please note that you should reach out to Adobe’s consulting team for asssistance on this so that they can set up the inputs in the most optimal way to receive your offline data.
4. **Import from older version of CQ**  – This is a pretty straightforward way to import or upgrade from an older version of CQ. If you are familar with AEM, you can stop existing instance, if you have a stand alone instance of AEM replace the jar file, and restart

If you have an application server instance, you will follow these steps:
Stop existing instance, replace the war file and restart.

5. **Bulk Editor** – This feature provides a multitude of functionality within AEM. For starters, you can make large changes to content at once. Secondly, you can export content to CSV (Microsoft Excel) files.

Kautuk Sahni
([Adobe AEM Community](http://lp-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.html))